# Bootstrap 3.0.0 breaks the datepicker icon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6nUu7JkVYdTiWHbXhT3f?p=preview)

If you use 2.3.1, uncomment line 12 and you will see the button appearing correctly

Does anyone know how can I fix it for version 3.0.0-rc1?

Comment: do not waste time, you need to migrate to version 3 and change the path to glyps... . Better use something in hand like this -> http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/jquery.simple-dtpicker.html

Comment: I added "~/Content/bootstrap.css" and it worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPADTE**

The answer below was true for Bootstrap 3 Release Candidates, however the stable version does include the Glyphicons library which requires a base class and an individual icon class, ex:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

**Original answer:**

From the docs:

> With the launch of Bootstrap 3, icons have been moved to a [separate
>   repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-glyphicons). This keeps
>   the primary project as lean as possible, makes it easier for folks to
>   swap icon libraries, and makes Glyphicons icon fonts more readily
>   available to more people outside Bootstrap.

That means you need to include the glyphicons separately, you can use [Bootstrap's own icons](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-glyphicons) or another library like [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Answer (score 16):

To fix the icon issue in bootstrap-datepicker for bootstrap 3.0 do this:

// ../bootstrap-datepicker.js

*Search the next content and replace*

replace `<i class="icon-arrow-left"/>`

with `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"/>`

replace `<i class="icon-arrow-right"/>`

with `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"/>`

replace `.toggleClass('icon-arrow-left icon-arrow-right');`

with `.toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-left glyphicon-arrow-right');`

**That's all, I hope it works for you.**

Comment: If you want to use font awesome instead of glyphicons: change `icon-arrow-left` to `fa fa-arrow-left` and `icon-arrow-right` to `fa fa-arrow-right` for the classes in the HTML, and put `fa-arrow-left fa-arrow-right` in the `.toggleClass` call.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `.icon-calendar` does not exist in 3.0.0-rc1.

[2.3.1 css](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)

[3.0.0-rc1 css](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css)

The only icons mentioned in 3.0.0-rc1 CSS seem to be related to navigation. It also looks like they may have renamed it to `.glyphicon-calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

So, instead of, I prefer add the another  for works with Bootstrap V2 and V3.

```
<tr>'+
    '<th class="prev">'+
        '<i class="icon-arrow-left"/>'+                 
        '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"/>'+ //Añadido para solucionar el bug con BS3
    '</th>'+
    '<th colspan="5" class="switch"></th>'+
    '<th class="next">'+
        '<i class="icon-arrow-right"/>'+
        '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"/>'+ //Añadido para solucionar el bug con BS3
    '</th>'+
'</tr>'+
```

Comment: I have tu use BS2 and BS3 in differents projects with the same datepicker library and works in this way, maybe it is a bad practice, but it is always a bad practice touch the core library, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ge_eventbundle_event_eventDate').datetimepicker({
              language: "fr", 
              format: "yyyy-mm-dd  hh:ii",
              autoclose: true,
              todayBtn: true,
              fontAwesome: 'font-awesome',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> find below line in bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

```
this.fontAwesome = j.fontAwesome || this.element.data("font-awesome") || false;
```

> Replace with this

```
this.fontAwesome = j.fontAwesome || this.element.data("font-awesome") || true;
```

Answer (score 0):

On your bootstrap-datetimepicker.js open it and change the following

```
this.icons = {
  leftArrow: this.fontAwesome ? 'fa-arrow-left' : (this.bootcssVer === 3 ? 'glyphicon-arrow-left' : 'icon-arrow-left'),
  rightArrow: this.fontAwesome ? 'fa-arrow-right' : (this.bootcssVer === 3 ? 'glyphicon-arrow-right' : 'icon-arrow-right')
}
this.icontype = this.fontAwesome ? 'fa' : 'glyphicon';
```

To the following

```
this.icons = {
  leftArrow: this.fontAwesome ? 'fa-arrow-left' : (this.bootcssVer === 3 ? 'fa-arrow-left' : 'fa-arrow-left'),
  rightArrow: this.fontAwesome ? 'fa-arrow-right' : (this.bootcssVer === 3 ? 'fa-arrow-right' : 'fa-arrow-right')
}
this.icontype = this.fontAwesome ? 'fa' : 'fa';
```

Try this method and see

Comment: Unfortunately, file `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` doesn't contains such lines.