# How to setup bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to use the [bootstrap-datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/). The problem is that I am getting only the input filed without no styles.
Here are my includes:

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="../css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../js/assets/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/assets/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/assets/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
```

here is the html:

```
<div class="input-append date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input id="dp3" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012"/>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar" id="cal2"></i></span>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript :

```
$('#dp3').datepicker();
```

what is wrong??

**Note:**
No when I focus into the input the calender appears but there is no icon.

Comment: yes, copy paste error. fixed question.

Comment: nope, no error. I am totally lost...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40491/discussion-between-vlad-ioffe-and-totymedli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [this version](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) than you have to use it with Bootstrap 2 because it doesn't fully support Bootstrap 3. If you use Bootstrap 3 you have to deal with the [icon problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197270/bootstrap-3-0-0-breaks-the-datepicker-icon) yourself, by adding a different icon, use a button instead or completely remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems you're missing to add the following `css` files.

1. bootstrap css
2. bootstrap datepicker css

Make sure, you add it.

See here the working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/354/)

Comment: Sorry forgot it in the question, I have included them. edited the question.

Comment: @VladIoffe have you checked my fiddle?

Comment: there is no need to downgrade check this jsfiddle with calendar icon http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/355.  You need to add another css file from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/calendar-o/

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, either make this call when DOM is loaded:

```
$(function() {
  $('#dp3').datepicker();
});
```

OR

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#dp3').datepicker();
       });
```

Comment: My code looks as you posted here, but I still can't see the icon.

Comment: its not same i call it in document.ready but you not post like that